# Is it possible to use a bundle id named "com.mycompany.appname.mobile"?

Tags: ios, xcode7

I have used bundle id named as "com.mycompany.appname.mobile" until now.
(four group url address) 
After I updated xcode version from 6.4 to 7.0, when I build and run the app on iphone device, xcode shows like this error message.

[image]

I should use "com.mycompany.appname.mobile" but Should I change bundle ID? 
Is it possible to solve this problem keeping "com.mycompany.appname.mobile"?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

Cause was to set incorrect provisioning profile in xcode -> project -> targets -> general -> identity -> team. (change a provisioning profile from incorrect to suitable)

In addition, I have known that app id can bee generated used bundle id already, but only a unique bundle id in apple developer site.